# How do I increase the number of evaluation points in geom_smooth for ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a plot and adding a basic loess smooth line to it.

```
qplot(Age.GTS2004., X.d18O,data=deepsea, geom=c('point')) + 
geom_smooth(method="loess",se=T,span=0.01, alpha=.5, fill='light blue',color='navy')
```

The problem is that the line is coming out really choppy.  I need more evaluation point for the curve in certain areas. Is there a way to increase the number of evaluation points without having to reconstruct geom_smooth?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but have you tried adjusting span?

Comment: Span controls the smoothness; a typical span is more like 0.7. Why are you setting it so low?

Comment: Because at one end I have thousands of points and at the other only dozens.  One I need to see the detail at the one end, which is not coming out since there are not enough points that make up the smoothed line.  It only shows about 25 points but I need about 500 points where the smoothed loess curve is evaluated.

Comment: @AndrewRedd Did you find any way to increase data points while fitting data??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `n` parameter, as documented in `stat_smooth`.

Answer (score 2):

Hadley: The documentation leads people astray.  `geom_smooth` does not document that it accepts parameters on behalf of `stat_smooth`, nor is there any link on that page to `stat_smooth` for continued reading.

I figured the parameter was buried on some other help page, but I landed here to clue in where.